# ASP.NET MVC + NinjectWebCommon

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am going with "Freeman pro asp.net mvc 5" book (chapter 7).

The problem is:

The code in NinjectWebCommon.cs never executes, so I am constantly getting error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." It seems like web server doesn't see this file at all, I have breakpoints on every method and never get to any of them when running application.

First, I followed all the instructions in the book, and made the project by myself. I got this error.

Second, I downloaded code examples from official site, opened the project and trying to run it. I still got this error.

Third, I created a new , absolutely simple mvc5+ninject application, and I still got this error.

Any ideas?

So to be clear, just these steps:
1. I am going to http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430265290
2. I am downloading source code
3. I am opening source code example from chapter 7 in VS 2015
4. Without making any changes to the code, I am pressing F5 and enjoying the error in the browser:
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
..
[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.ProductController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]

the controller code is simple:

```
    public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }
}
```

Next, I have my own implementation of dependency resolver in code:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
    {
        kernel = kernelParam;
        AddBindings();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();

        mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product>
        {
            new Product {Name = "Football", Price = 25},
            new Product {Name = "Surf board", Price = 179},
            new Product {Name = "Running shoes", Price = 95}
        });

        kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
    }
}
```

And finally, I use it in class NinjectWebCommon, like this:

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
    }
```

Comment: Post the code for the controller.

Comment: @OwenPauling why? anyway, added to the post

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers.ProductController'.
>   Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

The error message is clear: your controller does not have a parameterless constructor (as confirmed by your code). This is of course intentional since you require an IProductRepository. You simply need to provide a binding for the IProductRepository so that Ninject knows how to create this dependency.

Comment: you are right. I have added the rest of the code to the post. There is binding that should be set in RegisterServices(). The problem is, I do not see that RegisterServices() executes at any stage: I have the breakpoint on this method, and I do not reach it when I start the application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, the reason was: never use damn # symbol in your path to projects.

Ninject, Visual studio or whatever cannot resolve it properly and fail to load dependancies.